# Why Drupal is slow on WSL

Tags: 9

Trying Drupal 9.3.15 on Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). However it's very slow when browsing to `http://localhost/drupal9` and it timeout most of the times, **what could be the reason behind this slowness?**

1. Created directory for Drupal: `mkdir ~/projects/drupal9`
2. Download Drupal using composer: `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project ~/projects/drupal9`
3. Link my new project to `/var/www/drupal9`: `sudo ln -sT ~/projects/drupal9/web /var/www/drupal9`
4. Install Drupal using drush: `drush site:install`
5. Configure nginx:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  root /var/www;

  index index.php;

  location /drupal9 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
  }

  location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^ /drupal9/index.php;
  }

  location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
  }
```

Comment: The reason for the slowness is WSL itself. There is a file performance IO penalty on Mac and Windows due to how virtualization works. The general advice especially on Windows is to do "all of your work" inside of Linux. Do not mount anything in from Windows. Second to that, make sure you are allocating enough RAM (like 4GB) and storage resources to that virtual instance. Third, throw in memcache or redis so you arent using the database as a cache store.

Comment: Also, upgrade to WSL2 if you aren't already on it.

Comment: @kevin, thanks a lot, upgrading from WSL 1 to WSL 2 fixed the unnormal slowness. Please put this advice as an answer to be selected as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly Drupal related, but nonetheless:

If you are on WSL1, upgrade to WSL2.

The reason for the slowness is WSL itself. There is a file performance IO penalty on Mac and Windows due to how virtualization works. The general advice especially on Windows is to do "all of your work" inside of Linux. Do not mount anything in from Windows. Second to that, make sure you are allocating enough RAM (like a minimum of 4GB) and storage resources to that virtual instance. Third, throw in memcache or redis so you arent using the database as a cache store.

Comment: In reference to "do all your work" inside Linux, note that VSCode and PHPStorm can both be installed in Windows and then configured to remotely access your WSL2 files without a performance penalty.

Comment: Yes, because they are ssh'ing in with the Remote Desktop plug-ins. When I say Mount I basically mean any file volumes or docker volumes.